# Trying to flatten XML using SQL Server XMLOPEN however values are repeating in nested rows

Tags: sql-server, formatting, attributes, tags

Using OPENXML in SQL Server I am trying to produce a flat representation as shown below.

I've created a simple example here that reproduces my challenge.

| Name | CodeName | Sequences | Sequence | Direct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 12 | PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 30 | RUGMU/IGDEB/LEESA |

The XML example is given here

```
<HID Name="LEESA5" CodeName="YBAS" Sequences="12,30">
    <Direct Sequence="12">PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
    <Direct Sequence="30">RUGMU/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
</HID>
```

The SQL Server code I am using is:

```
declare @idoc int, @XML XML =
    '<HID Name="LEESA5" CodeName="YBAS" Sequences="12,30">
      <Direct Sequence="12">PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
      <Direct Sequence="30">RUGMU/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
    </HID>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XML  

select * from OPENXML(@idoc,'/HID/*')
with
(
Name varchar(10) '../@Name'
,CodeName varchar(10) '../@CodeName'
,Sequences varchar(10) '../@Sequences'
,Sequence varchar(10) '@Sequence'
,Direct varchar(100) '../Direct'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

However the result has the final value repeat rather than use the value from

| Name | CodeName | Sequences | Sequence | Direct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 12 | PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 30 | PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA |

There is clearly something I don't understand however after hours of searching and fiddling I keep getting the same result. Any pointer towards how to reference the final column values would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why are you still using OPENXML? The much more convenient .nodes(), .query() and .value() XQuery methods have been supported since around SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `OPENXML` try using the XQuery methods instead, e.g.:

```sql
declare @XML XML =
N'<HID Name="LEESA5" CodeName="YBAS" Sequences="12,30">
  <Direct Sequence="12">PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
  <Direct Sequence="30">RUGMU/IGDEB/LEESA</Direct>
</HID>';

select
  hid.value(N'@Name', N'varchar(10)') as [Name],
  hid.value(N'@CodeName', N'varchar(10)') as [CodeName],
  hid.value(N'@Sequences', N'varchar(10)') as [Sequences],
  direct.value(N'@Sequence', N'varchar(10)') as [Sequence],
  direct.value(N'(text())[1]', N'varchar(100)') as [Direct]
from @XML.nodes(N'/HID') x(hid)
cross apply hid.nodes(N'Direct') y(direct);
```

Produces:

| Name | CodeName | Sequences | Sequence | Direct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 12 | PUNED/BODAS/OSINA/IGDEB/LEESA |
| LEESA5 | YBAS | 12,30 | 30 | RUGMU/IGDEB/LEESA |

Comment: Thanks @alwayslearning that is great. I see how you reference the text() for the tag. I couldn't work that out for the node approach. So I guess you have to cross apply to go deeper into the nesting - makes sense. Thanks for the quick and specific response.

Comment: @BWard when dealing with nested tags always go down the path from the root element. Avoid using the parent axis, `..`, where possible because it's very inefficient.

Comment: got you thanks - I did experience the performance issue using previous level (..) ! Most appreciated - had been battling with OPENXML but nodes is so much cleaner!